# Windows folder in c drive

Tags: windows

can anybody tell
what is the significance of "C:\Windows" windows folder in c drive
What it contains?
are any processes, using the content of this folder

Answer (score 4):

the c:\windows folder usually contains the core files  of the Windows  operation system, virtually all processes are using the content of this folder

Answer (score 3):

The Windows folder on the C:\ drive on a windows system contains **all** important and vital system files. Everything that is related to the core system is stored here. This does not include third party programs, which go in C:\Programs.

In other words: Do not touch.